# Linux script help needed

Tags: linux, scripting

I am trying to create a script that will use the /etc/passwd file to create a listing like this:

Full Name: Blah Blah  User Account: bblah  User ID: 5000  Last logged in: Sun Feb 21 18:13
Full Name: Mike Mike  User Account: mmike  User ID: 5001  Last logged in: Sun Feb 21 18:13

With my script, I get it to show 
Full Name: Blah Blah  User Account: bblah  User ID: 1000
because I grep the 1000 accounts in my passwd file.  As soon as I do the 5000 series, I get all the full names, then all the user accounts, and then all the user ids listed.  How do I go about fixing this?  How do I go about adding the "Last logged in" bit?

Is there a way to do this without using awk?

Script so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
passfile=/etc/passwd

for i in  $(grep 5000 ${passfile} | cut -d : -f 5)
do


        account=$(grep 5000 /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 3)
        username=$(grep 5000 /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f 1)
        echo Full Name:${i} Username: ${username} User ID: ${account} Last login: ${lastlogin)
done
```

Comment: Do you want to list all accounts or specific username/id?

Comment: all accounts.  I want it to do it like this:  name: name username: username  user id: 1001  last login: x.x.x.x name name username: username  user id: 1002 last login x.x.x.x

Answer (score 2):

Last logged in is done by last command:

```
last username
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -en "BEGIN{\n}{\n    system(var)\n}\n" > h.awk
while read in; \
 do \
  uname=`echo $in | sed -r 's/:/\ /g' | awk '{print $1}'`; \
  p1=`echo $in | sed -r 's/:/\ /g' | awk '{print "name: "$5, "username: "$1, "id: "$3}'`; \
  p2=`echo | awk  -f ./h.awk var="last $uname| head -n 1"|awk '{print $5 $6}'`; \
  echo $p1 last login: $p2; \
done < /etc/passwd
```

If you need more detail of last login to be prompted, use this one:

```
echo -en "BEGIN{\n}{\n    system(var)\n}\n" > h.awk
while read in; \
 do \
  uname=`echo $in | sed -r 's/:/\ /g' | awk '{print $1}'`; \
  p1=`echo $in | sed -r 's/:/\ /g' | awk '{print "name: "$5, "username: "$1, "id: "$3}'`; \
  p2=`echo | awk  -f ./h.awk var="last $uname| head -n 1"|awk '{print $4" "$5 $6" "$7}'`; \
  echo $p1 last login: $p2; \
done < /etc/passwd
```